# How to return an object with lucene?

Tags: java, apache, lucene

I've been following this [tutorial](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html) on lucene. Say instead of:

```
private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, String title, String isbn) throws IOException {
    Document doc = new Document();
    doc.add(new TextField("title", title, Field.Store.YES));

    // use a string field for isbn because we don't want it tokenized
    doc.add(new StringField("isbn", isbn, Field.Store.YES));
    w.addDocument(doc);
}
```

I pass an object of my own class called car along with it's instance variables

```
private static void addDoc(IndexWriter w, Car thisCar, String name, String brand) throws IOException {

Document doc = new Document();
doc.add(new TextField("name", name, Field.Store.YES));
doc.add(new StringField("brand", brand, Field.Store.YES));
w.addDocument(doc);}
```

Is there a way where I can search for the name and brand and have lucene return the Car object instead of the individual string variables? I've looked through the docs for document class in lucene but can't seem to find anything.